# How to set root path relative to rootDir after compilation

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsc

My tsconfig

```
{
...
     "baseUrl": "./",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "paths": {
          "*/.": [
            "node_modules/*",
        "src/*"
      ],
}
```

and index.ts imports something:

```
import 'app'
```

After compilation I need the path relative to rootDir:

```
import './app'
```

How to do it?